# How to find the text that depends inherently on the month

Tags: javascript, date, translation

In french, you say "Le mois d'avril", and you say "Le mois de septembre". Depending on the month, you use either "d'" or "de". It's similar to the distinction between "a" and "an" in english.

Is there a way to automatically get the right wording in Javascript, or do I need to hard code it?

I thought Intl or Moment might help but up to now I cannot find a solution in these libs.

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot to test. Avril, août and octobre.

```js
const getMonth = d => {
  const month = d.toLocaleString('fr-fr', {month:'long'});
  return `${"ao".includes(month[0]) ? `d'` : `de `}${month}`
}

console.log(getMonth(new Date('2023-04-05')))
console.log(getMonth(new Date('2023-05-05')))
console.log(getMonth(new Date('2023-08-05')))
console.log(getMonth(new Date('2023-10-05')))
```